# Second time data loaded from cosmos db, list view does not update

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am learning xamarin forms. I have many data stored in my cosmos db.

I would like to get 14 items every time I scroll in my listview.

My problem is the execution is fast and the data do is not downloaded

Here is the initial code when the APP start :

```cs
    int ndxData = 14;
    int InitDataNulber = 14;
    List<MyCommunityModel> MyListFollowVar;
    ObservableRangeCollection<MyCommunityModel> datasource;
    void Param()
    {
    
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            datasource = new ObservableRangeCollection<MyCommunityModel>();
    
            MyListFollowVar = new List<MyCommunityModel>();
            MyListFollowVar = await OnGetPerson(MyuserGlobalId, 0);
    
            MyFollowerCollectionList.ItemSizingStrategy = ItemSizingStrategy.MeasureFirstItem;
            MyFollowerCollectionList.ItemsSource = datasource = new ObservableRangeCollection<MyCommunityModel>(MyListFollowVar);
            MyFollowerCollectionList.RemainingItemsThreshold = 5;
            MyFollowerCollectionList.RemainingItemsThresholdReached += Followers_RemainingItemsThresholdReached;
    
        });
    }
```

Here is how I get new data/item:

```cs
    private void Followers_RemainingItemsThresholdReached(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    
    
        MyListFollowVar.AddRange(await OnGetPerson(MyuserGlobalId, ndxData));
    
        //I would like to wait here for the data to be download 
        // then continue
    
    
    
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            datasource.AddRange(MyListFollowVar.Skip(ndxData).Take(InitDataNulber));
            ndxData += InitDataNulber;
    
        });
    
        
    
    }
```

Here is how I get item :

```cs
async Task<List<MyCommunityModel>> OnGetPerson(string MyUserid, int NumbrToSkip)
    {

        List<MyCommunityModel> TMMPMyListFollowVar = new List<MyCommunityModel>();

          List<UserInteractionModel> UsersInteractionList = await UserInteractionManager.GetFollowedUserInteraction(MyUserid, NumbrToSkip.ToString());

           
            CommunityUser = new MyCommunityModel();
            if (UsersInteractionList != null)
            {

                foreach (var u in UsersInteractionList)
                {

                 
                    CommunityUser = new MyCommunityModel();
                    CommunityUser.MyId = new Guid(u.UserToFollowId);
                    TMMPMyListFollowVar.Add(CommunityUser);
                }

               
                return TMMPMyListFollowVar;


            }

            return null;
        }

    }
```

Here is the call from cosmos db :

```cs
    public async static Task<List<UserInteractionModel>> GetFollowedUserInteraction(string Userid,string NumberToSkip)
    {
    
    
    
    
    
        List<UserInteractionModel> UsersInteractionList = new List<UserInteractionModel>();
    
    
      
        string sql = "";
    
      
        
        if (NumberToSkip == "0")
        {
    
        sql = "SELECT top 14 * FROM (SELECT * FROM  u WHERE u.followeruserid='" + Userid + "' and u.complete=false ) as c ORDER BY c.Updated desc";
    
        }
        else {                
        sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM  u WHERE u.followeruserid='" + Userid + "' and u.complete=false ) as c ORDER BY c.Updated desc   OFFSET " + NumberToSkip + " LIMIT 14";
        }
    
        QueryDefinition query = new QueryDefinition(sql);
    
    
    
        using (FeedIterator<UserInteractionModel> iterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<UserInteractionModel>(
         queryDefinition: query,
         requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions()
         {
             MaxItemCount = -1,
    
         }))
    
        {
    
            while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
            {
                FeedResponse<UserInteractionModel> result = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();
    
                UsersInteractionList.AddRange(result.Resource);
    
    
            }
    
            return UsersInteractionList;
    
    
    
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Does OnGetPerson work?  Where is that code?

Comment: @Jason yes it works because when the function start I have my 14 items

Comment: And have you debugged it to see what it is doing differently on the 2nd call?

Comment: @Jason I can see that the data is loading in "datasource" list  but the list is not refreshed on screen.

Comment: Note: there are numerous xamarin forms questions about listview not updating. there may be one that answers a simiilar situation, but your code with `await` on a `parameter` is less common; not sure that has been explained before, so I won't mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: Since data has been loading in datasource, maybe you could manually try using OnPropertyChanged to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

`async` / `await` can do the waiting for you. But the method needs to be declared `async`, and (I think) the `await` has to be a separate statement, not on a parameter:

```cs
private async void Followers_RemainingItemsThresholdReached(...)
{
  var result = await OnGetPerson(MyuserGlobalId, ndxData);
  // This line isn't reached until OnGetPerson finishes.
  MyListFollowVar.AddRange(result);
  ...
}
```